# Is a nuclear detonation wave on a gas giant like Jupiter possible?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I've seen papers doing detailed calculations showing that it's not possible to create a propagating nuclear detonation in Earth's atmosphere or oceans, e.g., [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.20.316).  Is it known whether it's similarly impossible for this to happen on a gas giant like Jupiter (I assume it's not realistic otherwise astronomers would see such detonations)?

Note that while a number of questions have asked whether a nuclear weapon could turn Jupiter into a star **this is not what is being asked here**.  The conditions for sustaining nuclear fusion at equilibrium are very different from asking if it's possible to create a propagating detonation.

Comment: Can you access the paper to read it? I can only access the abstract, which spoils my plan to find an equation or inequality governing whether such detonation is possible, then plug in Jovian values. If you can find such criteria, feel free to edit them into the question.

Comment: Just grab it from sci-hub.se.  But, one reason I didn't try to do that myself is that you need to do more than just substitute the constants from Jupiter as the original paper focuses on Nitrogen Nitrogen fusion reactions as the most relevant in earth's atmosphere so you'd need to know what nuclear reactions to look at (which I don't know but you might)..

Comment: Every sci-hub mirror I tried was poorly. If you know a good one for the UK, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions for propagating fusion burn were not well understood at the time, as one might expect, but we know them pretty well now. A key paper on the topic is this one:

[Laser Compression of Matter to Super-High Densities: Thermonuclear (CTR) Applications](https://www.nature.com/articles/239139a0)

The key concept here is that the fusion propagation velocity is a function of density - simply because the alphas don't have to go as far before hitting some fuel. But even at ridiculous density, the fuel mass is disassembling even faster, and so there's a race while you try to get as much fusion as possible in the short time when the fuel is "dwelling" at maximum density.

For instance, in NIF, the density is about 100 times that of lead, and assuming a hot spot, the physical expansion of the fuel is still faster than the fusion propagation. This is why it is so hard to use ICF for power generation, as the fuel tends to blow itself apart too rapidly.

I am not familiar with Jupiter's lower-layer conditions, but I don't believe they reach this sort of density. That suggests it will not be possible for it to maintain a propagating burn, and that any fusion events that occur would cause the local area to essentially blow apart.

UPDATE: a little googling shows the conditions on Jupiter were much less extreme than I thought, about 300 K and 10 atm, so the fusion rate will be *tiny* and definitely not sustain ignition.